# Unable to delete PowerPoint Slides using Python-pptx

Tags: python, python-3.x, powerpoint, python-pptx

I am trying to delete PowerPoint slides containing a specific keywords using Python-pptx. If the keyword is present anywhere in the slide then that slide will be deleted. My code is given below:

```
from pptx import Presentation

String = 'Macro'

ppt = Presentation('D:\\Shaon\\pptss\\Regional.pptx')

for slide in ppt.slides:
    for shape in slide.shapes:
        if shape.has_text_frame:
            shape.text = String
            slide.delete(slide)

ppt.save('BODd.pptx')
```

After execution I am getting a memory error. No clue how to resolve this issue. How can I delete ppt slides using some specific keywords?

Comment: I think the problem may be due to the fact that you're modifying one of the items being iterated (which messes-up the iteration process).

Comment: What is the memory error?

Comment: @mattsap It only shows memory error.

Comment: @Martineau can I please help me how to resolve this issue?

Comment: Shaon: Sorry, I don't have `pptx` installed, which makes doing that difficult. One generic way of working around this kind of problem would be to create a _new_ presentation in the loop with just the things you want to keep in it (and then replace the original with that one afterwards).

Comment: @Shaon I mean, can you copy paste the message that's being shown to you? Also, martineau's solution sounds like a good way to go about doing it if you can't resolve the deletion issue.

Comment: There is no `Slide.delete()` method in `python-pptx`: https://python-pptx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/slides.html#slide-objects. Search on "python-pptx delete slide" for prior answers to this question, like here: https://github.com/scanny/python-pptx/issues/67

Comment: @scanny Can you guide me how to proceed? I am just a beginner..Found it difficult to resolve

Answer (score 3):

It is possible to delete the whole slides using the following code. So just use this before generating the slides to have a clean and empty PowerPoint file. By changing the index, you can also delete the specific slides.

```
import os
import pptx.util
from pptx import Presentation

cwd = os.getcwd()
prs = Presentation(cwd + '\\ppt.pptx')
for i in range(len(prs.slides)-1, -1, -1): 
    rId = prs.slides._sldIdLst[i].rId
    prs.part.drop_rel(rId)
    del prs.slides._sldIdLst[i]
```

Comment: This worked for me and is very flexible, since on can use the index of a slide. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can delete a slide with a specific index value with the following code using the pptx library:

```
from pptx import Presentation
#  create slides ------
presentation = Presentation('new.pptx') 

xml_slides = presentation.slides._sldIdLst  
slides = list(xml_slides)
xml_slides.remove(slides[index])
```

So to delete the first slide, `index` would be 0.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to delete all slides but the cover from one pptx file to reuse the layouts and the best solution I got was to loop Ferhat´s answer.

It worked :)

```
# Ferhat´s showed us how to list the slides:

xml_slides = prs.slides._sldIdLst  
slides = list(xml_slides)

# Then I loop for all except the first (index 0):

for index in range(1,len(slides)):
    xml_slides.remove(slides[index])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in range(0,6,1):
        delete_slides(prs, 0)

def delete_slides(presentation, index):
        xml_slides = presentation.slides._sldIdLst  
        slides = list(xml_slides)
        xml_slides.remove(slides[index])
```

Here is code, you can use it for deleting your slides from 0 index. As you can see, there is an range, by using for loop, you can set how many pages you want to delete. Also, if you are going to delete your page from end just use -1.

Like this:

```
for i in range(0,6,1):
        delete_slides(prs, -1)

def delete_slides(presentation, index):
        xml_slides = presentation.slides._sldIdLst  
        slides = list(xml_slides)
        xml_slides.remove(slides[index])
```

Hope it will help you.